# Google doesn't ignore ?SID when its disallowed in robots.txt

Tags: magento-1.9, seo

I have disallowed? SID in my [robots.txt](http://www.singhcycle.com/robots.txt) but Google still likes to show them in search results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not put this in your robots.txt. It is better to do this in the search console from Google.

There is a function there for parameters under

> Crawl -> URL Parameters -> Add Parameter

Source: [Click here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6080548?hl=en&rd=2)

And if you don´t want these to come up even there is this setting also

> ```
> Go to Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Web -> Session Validation Settings
> ```

disable config Use SID on Frontend = No

This could also be needed in your case to make it work with the .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.singhcycle\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.singhcycle.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What I find it strange Google bot is respecting the other url parameters its only with ?SID

Comment: Can you try and see if it works that way? I´ve also made an udpate at the bottom to my answer

Comment: This is what search console say for SID."From parameters that Googlebot discovered on your site here is a list of parameters that appear not to change the content of your pages. Google will ignore these. (If you're certain that this is incorrect, you can specify how you want these parameters to be handled.)" I don't want should be the appropriate way to handle is parameter.

Comment: SID is already added automatically to search console. I think I need to tell how to handle this parameter.

Answer (score 4):

The line `Disallow: ?SID` (or `Disallow: /?SID`) will block URLs like:

- `http://example.com/?SID`
- `http://example.com/?SIDD`
- `http://example.com/?SID/foo`

But it will **not** block URLs like:

- `http://example.com/foo?SID`
- `http://example.com/foo/?SID`

For the Googlebot, you can specify a wildcard (but this is not supported by all bots because it’s not part of the official robots.txt standard):

```
Disallow: /*?SID
```

This will block all URLs whose path starts with any string (indicated by `*`) followed by `?SID`.

---

Your current robots.txt seems to include `Disallow: /*?SID=`, which would block URLs like `http://example.com/foo?SID=bar`. So this should work. The only issue I can see in your robots.txt is that you include new lines in a record, which is not allowed.

So instead of

```
# Crawlers Setup
User-agent: *

# Directories
Disallow: /404/
```

it would have to be

```
# Crawlers Setup
User-agent: *
# Directories
Disallow: /404/
```

(But it’s likely that the Googlebot handles it correctly anyway.)

Comment: I got your point. I would remove the white lines to stick with robots.txt standards.